# toggle each div next to each link and fetch post data

Tags: jquery, toggle

I have the following html element in my body section:

```
<a class="tog" href="#">Click Me</a> 
<div class="result">
    This is a container div
</div> <br />
<a class="tog" href="#">Click Me</a> 
<div class="result">
    This is a container div
</div>
```

and the head section contains this:

```
.result{
    display: none;
}
```

What I want to do, while clicking on each link `<a>`, the next `div` will toggle and at the same time it will fetch data from another page into that `div` by a `post`. So my jQuery code is:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $(".tog").click(function () {
        if (!$(this).next(".result").data('loaded')) {
            $.post("anotherpage.php", {
                id1: "value1"
            }, function (data) {
                $(this).next(".result").html(data);
                $(this).next(".result").data('loaded', true);
            });
        }
        $(this).next(".result").slideToggle("slow");
        return false;
    });
});
```

Each div next to each link `<a>` is toggling well by the above code. But the data is not fetching from another page. If I exclude $(this).next from each point of the above code like this:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $(".tog").click(function () {
        if (!$(".result").data('loaded')) {
            $.post("anotherpage.php", {
                id1: "value1"
            }, function (data) {
                $(".result").html(data);
                $(".result").data('loaded', true);
            });
        }
        $(this).next(".result").slideToggle("slow");
        return false;
    });
});
```

Each div is toggling after clicking each link and fetching `post` data from another page also, but clicking on any link is fetching data to all `div`s together at the same time.

My query is how can I revise the code, so that clicking on each link will toggle `div` next to that link and fetch data to the next `div` only?

Answer (score 0):

I believe the issue here is that the conext of `$(this)` is lost within the ajax-wrapper. so you'll need to store reference to the original element within the click function, and call the cached object within the success function.

```
$(".tog").click(function(){
    var $this = $(this); //cached reference
```

then later on..

```
},function(data){   
    //note how we use $this, instead of $(this)
    $this.next(".result").html(data);
    $this.next(".result").data('loaded',true);
```

Comment: Yes, your guess was right. the problem is solved, now everything is working as I expected. Thanks Ohgodwhy for your help